# How can an animation be sent behind another object in honeycomb?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have two fragments called frag1 & frag2 that are in a linearlayout with horizontal orientation.

I want to animate frag2 to seem to hide behind frag1 and then reappear with new contents.  Is it possible to set the z-order or something similar so that I can use a simple ObjectAnimator that changes translationX?

```
ObjectAnimator right = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(details, "translationX", start, details.getWidth()+start);
right.setDuration(duration);
right.setRepeatCount(1);
right.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.REVERSE);
right.start();
```

The above works fine, but frag2 (details) moves in front of frag1.  I want it behind.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the `View` that contains `frag1` after the `View` that contains `frag2`in your xml layout file, then `frag1` will appear in front of `frag2` and not the other way round. Ordering is important.